# How to fix pink mini applications in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, graphics

After recent Windows 7 update, the mini application for wheather or system performance started to display incorrectly in pink. I have two machines featuring this bug, a notebook with integrated Nvidia graphics, and a desktop with an AMD 4850; so I assume no error on the hardware part.

How do I fix this?

I tried `scf /scannow` and it did fine some errors that it could not repair. Another source implied that an update could have been stuck, so I tried the Update Readiness Tool for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB947821), without success after reboot.

[image: Screenshot of mini applications appearing in pink]

Comment: The whole Windows looks pink, so try to change the Windows color in the control panel.

Comment: Did one of the updates install Internet Explorer 11?

Comment: @ZippyV I don't know if the updates in question was IE11, but I can confrim that IE11 is installed. (I do not own the machines, I am trying to fix this.)

Comment: Why would you want to get rid of that? It’s so pretty. All you need now are a [ponies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19479/131979). ◕ ◡ ◕

Comment: @null (“…a *few* ponies” ¬_¬)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the comment I was able to find [a different thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/my-windows-7-weather-gadget-on-my-desktop-has/e44a7a76-1d9f-4168-bdc6-b920cd87df60) where it was said that there is an issue with the gadgets if there is 125% zoom. Changing back to 100% solved the issue for now.

[image: Solved pink gadget issue screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

That’s not pink, it’s magenta (web-code #ff00ff).

## Technical/Background

It’s not a rule, but since that color tends to rarely come up naturally in most pictures, convention has traditionally been to use magenta in places where an image is supposed to be transparent. That way, the program that displays the image will skip over pixels containing magenta, and thus create transparent areas.

Another way to create transparency is to use a transparency mask which (usually) is a greyscale or black-and-white image with black (or shades of grey) wherever the image is supposed to be displayed and white (or lighter shades of grey) wherever the image is supposed to be transparent/translucent.

## Application

What seems to be happening in your case is that the transparent color is [leaking out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb676240.aspx). It could be that an update changed how the sidebar works, but you said that the system-file checker could not fix some errors; you should check to see if the files it mentions are related to the sidebar or the gadgets. If so, then try running `sfc` in safe-mode because the sidebar won’t be run, so the files should be modifiable.

Comment: Ah, I see you found a solution. In that case, what’s probably happening is that when you increased the DPI, the scaling algorithm [messed up the images](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/a2c0c4cf-c294-4284-afe4-50325bafa0fc/reduce-rounding-errors-magenta-fringe-on-animated-gif-files). This is common with transparent images; the anti-aliasing effect of resizing [rarely plays well](http://i.imgur.com/kru1g.png) with alpha-blending.